# How to configure Paypal in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK
I downloaded this and i have tested it with simple php but i don't know where to put these files in which folder for CodeIgniter
https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK/blob/develop/samples/CaptureIntentExamples/RunAll.php

```
`Creating an Order
Code:
// Construct a request object and set desired parameters
// Here, OrdersCreateRequest() creates a POST request to /v2/checkout/orders
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCreateRequest;
$request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
$request->prefer('return=representation');
$request->body = [
                     "intent" => "CAPTURE",
                     "purchase_units" => [[
                         "reference_id" => "test_ref_id1",
                         "amount" => [
                             "value" => "100.00",
                             "currency_code" => "USD"
                         ]
                     ]],
                     "application_context" => [
                          "cancel_url" => "https://example.com/cancel",
                          "return_url" => "https://example.com/return"
                     ] 
                 ];

try {
    // Call API with your client and get a response for your call
    $response = $client->execute($request);

    // If call returns body in response, you can get the deserialized version from the result attribute of the response
    print_r($response);
}catch (HttpException $ex) {
    echo $ex->statusCode;
    print_r($ex->getMessage());
}`.
```

Comment: Any Help will be Appreciated.

Comment: refer to this `https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/setup-sdk/#`

Comment: @MohammadImran Yes i followed this link but it is not in codeigniter.
Where should i save my  composer paypal Files

Comment: Install the SDK into the application folder. `composer require paypal/paypal-checkout-sdk 1.0.1`.  `$config['composer_autoload']` to `TRUE` or your custom path.

Comment: how to replace namespace and use keyword ? they are throwing error